# Ionic Geolocation always falls into error method

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, geolocation, gps

I'm continuously failing to achieve my desired results. All I want is to fetch the geolocation coordinates, if the device location is turned off, a prompt is show to enable the location without leaving the app, and device location gets turn on I've verified it manually.

But the problem is every time I try, I get fall into the error method

```
import { LocationAccuracy } from '@ionic-native/location-accuracy/ngx';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { Geolocation } = Plugins;

this.locationAccuracy.request(this.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).
then(() => {

      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ enableHighAccuracy: true }).then(loc => {

        alert('Position detected successfully' + loc);

      }).catch(error => {

        alert(error);

      });

    }).catch(deny => {

      alert('You denied the location');

    });
```

But there is something very strange, and that is just before launching the app, If I run google maps and locate my self, then my app works without any issue, otherwise it keep falling into error method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy. Here is how you get the current location with Capacitor:

Page class (**updated with error handling**):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { GeolocationPosition, Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { Geolocation } = Plugins;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  currentPos: GeolocationPosition;
  waitingForCurrentPosition = false;

  constructor() {
  }

  async getCurrentPos() {
    try {
      this.waitingForCurrentPosition = true;
      this.currentPos = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
      console.log(this.currentPos);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to get current position.', err);
    } finally {
      this.waitingForCurrentPosition = false;
    }
  }

}
```

Page template:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Capacitor Geolocation
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-button (click)="getCurrentPos()" expand="block">
    <ion-spinner *ngIf="waitingForCurrentPosition"></ion-spinner>
    Get Current position
  </ion-button>

  <ul *ngIf="currentPos">
    <li>timestamp: {{ currentPos.timestamp }}</li>
    <li>coords:
      <ul>
        <li>latitude: {{ currentPos.coords.latitude }}</li>
        <li>longitude: {{ currentPos.coords.longitude }}</li>
        <li>accuracy: {{ currentPos.coords.accuracy }}</li>
        <li>altitudeAccuracy: {{ currentPos.coords.altitudeAccuracy }}</li>
        <li>altitude: {{ currentPos.coords.altitude }}</li>
        <li>speed: {{ currentPos.coords.speed }}</li>
        <li>heading: {{ currentPos.coords.heading }}</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ion-content>
```

The app will request permissions when you try to get a position (click on button).

This works on 2 test devices :

- OnePlus 6 (Android 10)
- BlackView A60 (Android Go)

I have tested it before on an iPhone 6S so it should also work for iOS.

I created a [basic demo in this repo](https://github.com/sebastienguillon/capacitor-geolocation).

Comment: the problem is it only works if the device GPS is turn on before opening the app, If I open the GPS during device it doesn't works.
PS the `cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy.` accuracy is just to prompt user to enable GPS if it's already turned off. If the GPS is already turn on prompts doesn't pops up

Comment: I see. I get the point of `cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy`, I don't know of a replacement for that in Capacitor only (I would be very interested as that Cordova package is heavy). However on my Android phone if I turn off location, then open the app, then turn on location, then request current position, it works.

Comment: why possibly it's not working in my case ?
just your idea

Comment: I don't know :(  I can post a link to my test project in a few minutes.